# how to convert string to integer

Tags: java, string, integer, simpledateformat

how do i convert `newValue2` to `Integer` because i am going to use it in a if statement ?

```
try {
    toDate=format2.parse(string1);
    java.util.Date newValue= new SimpleDateFormat(oldf).parse(string1);
     String newValue2 = new SimpleDateFormat(newf).format(newValue);

     int qwe = Integer.parseInt(newValue2);

     if (qwe < 8){

            String fixtime = ("08:00 PM");


            DateTime dateTime3 = dtf.parseDateTime(fixtime.toString());
            Period period = new Period(dateTime3, dateTime2);

            PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()

            .appendHours().appendSuffix(".")
            .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("")
            .toFormatter();

            String elapsed = formatter.print(period);

            table_4.setValueAt(elapsed,0,3);
                        }

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i try modifying it just to see the output of the `newValue2` in here :

```
try {
    toDate=format2.parse(string1);
    java.util.Date newValue= new SimpleDateFormat(oldf).parse(string1);
    String newValue2 = new SimpleDateFormat(newf).format(newValue);

    System.out.println (newValue2);

//  int qwe = Integer.parseInt(newValue2);

//  System.out.println(qwe);

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

example data to output:

```
07:00 AM 


System.out.println(newValue2);

07.00 0
```

Comment: You're already doing it, what's the problem?

Comment: Too bad you cannot accept a question, your question is actually an answer :)

Comment: well basically its not working.. and i don't know why.. And down voting is fine but can you just please tell me the reason why??. :D

Comment: The down votes are a signal/hint to others to close the question. You had not provided enough information for anyone to reasonably attempt to give you an answer. In the latest edit, it is more clear what you are doing wrong which is essentially what I had guessed already in my answer below.

Even still, I've know idea what you are trying to do precisely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this code:

```
 String newValue2 = new SimpleDateFormat(newf).format(newValue);
 int qwe = Integer.parseInt(newValue2);
```

... it seems highly likely that `newValue2` is actually some more complex date string and so can not be parsed to an `Integer`. Since `newValue` is actually a `Date` object, you could very likely just get whatever date field you are interested as an `int` directly from the [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object or more appropriately use a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

**EDIT:**
Based on the recent edit, this is probably what you want:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(newValue);
int qwe = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

P.S. If you use clearer, sensible variable names, more understanding could possibly be inferred from your code.

Comment: It's a bad idea to get the field directly from the `Date` object, because the methods that you could use to get it are deprecated.

Comment: @TimBender thank you for the last edit, I'm already trying to learn `java.util.calendar` well this solved my question :D big thanks!

Comment: *nod* by the way ... if you are focusing on 8 PM specifically, you may want to use `HOUR_OF_DAY` which considers hours to go from 0-23.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your code `newValue2` is a string containing a value from `SimpleDateFormat.format()`. Could you show the value of `newf`? If in case it will be all digits then what you are doing right now should be sufficient.

Comment: final String newf= ("h.00 0");